# Rounding Floating point numbers in Perl ..large inefficient but working solution

Tags: perl, floating-point, format, numbers, rounding

I had to round numbers that are a result of MySQL Querys. I didn't find a good solution for rounding in the correct way (truncating is not the correct way in my opinion).

I wrote this code that rounds float numbers and also formatted the numbers in the Spanish-Mexican way (using comma as a thousands, millions, etc.. (like 1425 -> 1,1425)

I know it is very inefficient, but it does the work in the right way. If you have any suggestions please let me know to make it more efficient.

Sorry for the Spanish variables and comments.. I'm Mexican!!!  ;)

```
sub formatea_numero                 # recibe una cifra sin formato y le agrega comas por cada 3 digitos
{
    my($importe_orig,$dec_a_redondear) = @_;

    my @digitos_corregido;
    my $contador=0;
    my $signo;
    my $importex;
    my $decimal_con_ceros_al_inicio = 0;

    ### SIGNO ######################
    ### Obteniendo el signo si lo tiene
    if($importe_orig=~/([-|+])(.*)/)    # SI TIENE SIGNO $1 EL NUM ES $2
    {
        $signo = $1;
        $importex = substr $importe_orig, 1;
    }
    else                                # NO TIENE SIGNO EL NUM ES $importe_orig
    {
        $importex = $importe_orig;
    }
    
    ###  DECIMALES ################
    ### Si tiene decimales.. se obtiene la parte entera y la parte decimal
    if($importex=~/\./)     # Tiene decimales
    {   
        if ($dec_a_redondear ne "" && $dec_a_redondear == 0)    # Caso Especial de que son 0 decimales a redondear
        {
            $importex=~/(.*)\.(.)(.*)/;
            $parte_entera = $1;
            $primer_decimal = $2;
            $resto_decimal = $3;
            if ($primer_decimal >= 5)
            {$parte_entera = $parte_entera+1;}          
        }
        else
        {
        
                if($importex=~/(.*)\.(.+)/)     # Parte entera $1  Parte decimal $2
                {
                    $parte_entera = $1;
                    $parte_decimal = $2;

                    if ($parte_decimal=~/^(0+).*/ ) # Caso especial si el decimal inicia en 0  ejem 3.0015 1.0000003  1.04  etc
                    {
                        $decimal_con_ceros_al_inicio =1;
                        $parte_decimal = "1" . $parte_decimal;
                    }           
                }
                
            ########### REDONDEAR DECIMALES 
            
                if ($decimal_con_ceros_al_inicio)
                {   
                    $dec_a_redondear =  1 + $dec_a_redondear;
                    $num_decimales_original = 1+ length $parte_decimal;
                }
                else
                {   $num_decimales_original = length $parte_decimal;}



                if ($dec_a_redondear>=0 && $dec_a_redondear < $num_decimales_original)
                {
                    
                    $parte_decimal_1 = substr($parte_decimal,0,$dec_a_redondear);   # se obtienen los digitos hasta el numero de decimales que se quiere redondear
                    $siguiente_decimal = substr($parte_decimal,$dec_a_redondear,1); # se obtiene el primer dígito a descartar .. si es mayor que 5 se le agrega uno al anterior digito
                    
                    if($siguiente_decimal >=5)
                    {
                        $largo_inicial_parte_decimal_1 = length $parte_decimal_1;           
                        $parte_decimal_1 = $parte_decimal_1 +1;
                        $largo_final_parte_decimal_1 = length $parte_decimal_1;

                        if($largo_final_parte_decimal_1 <= $largo_inicial_parte_decimal_1)
                        {
                            $parte_decimal = $parte_decimal_1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $parte_entera = $parte_entera + 1;
                            $parte_decimal = $parte_decimal_1 - 1;
                            $parte_decimal = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $parte_decimal = $parte_decimal_1;
                    }
                    

                    
                } # cierra if ($dec_a_redondear>0 && $dec_a_redondear < $num_decimales_original)

                    if ($decimal_con_ceros_al_inicio)
                    {   
                        $parte_decimal=~/^1(.+)/;
                        $parte_decimal = $1;
                    }



                ########### TERMINA DECIMALES (redondeando) 
        }   # Cierra if ($dec_a_redondear ne "" && $dec_a_redondear == 0)   # Caso Especial de que son 0 decimales a redondear
        
    } # cierra  if($importex=~/\./)     # Tiene decimales

        ########### FORMATEANDO LOS MILES ###########

    if($importex=~/\./)     # Tiene decimales
    {       
        @digitos = split(//,$parte_entera);
    }
    else                    # No tiene decimales
    {
        @digitos = split(//,$importex);
    }

    @digitos= reverse(@digitos);    
    
    foreach $digito(@digitos)
    {   
        if ($contador ==3)
        {
            push (@digitos_corregido,",");
            push (@digitos_corregido,$digito);
            $contador=1;
        }
        else
        {
            push (@digitos_corregido,$digito);
            $contador++;
        }
    }
    
    @digitos_corregido = reverse(@digitos_corregido);

    $importe2 = join('',@digitos_corregido);
    ### Termina de procesar la parte entera 
    
    
    ### Se integra el signo, la parte entera formateada y la parte decimal
    if($importex=~/\./)
    {
        if ($dec_a_redondear ne "" && $dec_a_redondear == 0)
        {   $importe2 = $importe2;}
        else
        {   
            if ($parte_decimal >0)
            {$importe2 = $importe2 . "." .$parte_decimal;}
            else
            {$importe2 = $importe2;}
        }
    }

    if($importe_orig=~/([-|+])(.*)/)
    {
        $importe2 = $signo . $importe2 ;        
    }

    return $importe2;
} # cierra sub formatea_numero                  # recibe una cifra sin formato y le agrega comas por cada 3 digitos
```

Comment: You wrote all this code to round numbers? That seems excessive. `int($num + 0.5)`? Should be plenty of math modules as well.

Comment: Also, you forgot to ask a question. Just dumping your code is not a good way to ask questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: @TLP slightly more complicated if you need to deal with negatives. also `perldoc -f int` recommends not using int for rounding. see also `perldoc -q round` which suggests implementing your own in some cases

Comment: [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be a better place for this question

Comment: So how do you want them rounded -- to a given number of decimal places? (For example, round every number to 2 decimal places.) Or is there some special criterion? (Sorry my Spanish is so miserable that I can't fully follow details of what your code is doing.) Do you know about `sprintf` builtin?

Comment: Sorry for the extent of the code.. thats exactly the question.. I tried to make it simple.. but I got a lot of "special cases", I wonder if I just over complicated it...   the idea was just to separate the decimal part from the integer part..  n is the number of decimals wanted... I obtained the n+1 decimal.  if it was  >5 then have to add one to the n decimal..  but what if the n decimal is 9?.. you have to add 1 to the n-1 decimal.. and what if tha n-1 decimal is the First decimal or is 9 again? those were some of the cases I tryed to solve..

Comment: the idea was to treat the decimal part as an integer.. and if there is the need to round "up" the decimal.. I just added 1 to it... then just check if the number "grew" to 1 order of magnitud... if that happened, then I have to add 1 to the integer part..

Comment: and the rest of the code is just to handle the special cases of a decimal starting with 0  like 2.00034  or 1.001  that kept giving me errors...

Comment: The sign was checked at the start.. if its negative.. I ignore the sing, round the number and at the return statement.. I jsut append the sign if its negative.

Comment: Also.. this is long code does two things at the same time..  rounds decimals.. and formats the  number with thousand signs...  1436.1268  -> 1,436.13  (rounding to 2 decimals)  or -2365423.8692 -> -2,365,423.87  (rounding 2 decimals)

Comment: This is my first post on the community.. I have to learn and make them better.. I will post specific questions.. less code and more English style variables and comments... thanks to all!!

Comment: Wow :) That's a lot of good work -- and a great exercise! (It could still be simpler, even when done manually by your algorithm.) As for posting here, this is a good question, but English would help in this case, to me anyway. (Perhaps just added short English comments?)

Comment: yes @zdim I will use english in the next code!!! and it will be smaller and simpler.. thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That seems to be a lot of code to round a number.  I can't quite follow all details in Spanish but if you have no special criteria  then basics may suffice, with [sprintf](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf)

```
$num = sprintf "%.2f", $num  if $num =~ /\./;
```

(This would add `.00` to an integer so I condition it on having `.`.  It'd better be a legit number.)

The `sprintf` uses [round half to even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even), per the IEEE754 [round to nearest (integer) ties to even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Roundings_to_nearest) rule.  (Windows may differ as it doesn't respect the IEEE spec but Strawberry Perl does round to even, thanks to ikegami for the note.)

There are also libraries, like [Math::Round](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Round) or [Math::BigFloat](https://perldoc.perl.org/Math::BigFloat). Please research this topic with care, in particular if your application is sensitive to details (like financial or scientific ones can be), since work with floating point is fraught with tricky points.  See also [perlfaq4 on rounding (etc)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4#Does-Perl-have-a-round()-function?-What-about-ceil()-and-floor()?-Trig-functions?)

Then you can add "thousands separator" (using `,` as desired), by replacing every triplet of digits by comma+itself, from the back (in the substring up to the decimal point).  Best wrap that in a sub

```
sub commify {
    local $_ = shift;  
    1 while s/^([-+]?[0-9]+)([0-9]{3})/$1,$2/;   
    return $_;
}
```

See [perlfaq5](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5#How-can-I-output-my-numbers-with-commas-added%3f) for more

Comment: To pass the precision  (in `$prec`) to it, `sprintf "%.${prec}f", $num`

Comment: Re "*I think that this isn't the case on Windows*", Strawberry Perl [rounds to even](https://gist.github.com/ikegami/781ac9624dfd03291d611ddcd53f529c)

Comment: Re "*`sprintf "%.${prec}f", $num`*", Or `sprintf "%.*f", $prec, $num`

Comment: Thanks a lot.. @zdim I will check Math::Round

Comment: And thanks for the commify routine.. That simplify a lot of my work.. thanks a lot